# sed pattern and multiline substitution

Tags: text-processing, sed

I need to parse a text file and replace a certain portion of it. I believe `sed` is the way to do it but not sure how to handle multiple lines with it

The pattern I am looking is

```
set cells { \  
cell1 \  
cell2 \  
cell3 \  
}
```

and I want to replace it with the contents of a variable.

Something like the following should do the trick, but it doesn't work on multiple lines. Any ideas?

`sed "s/set cells {.*}/set cells {$cell_variable}/" file`

Comment: If your command is working then you are just missing the `g`. `sed "s/set cells {.*}/set cells {$cell_variable}/g" file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to avoid perl as an extra tool to use. I could not make chaos solution to work for some reason, but reading a bit on sed I came up with an alternative which is here

```
sed "/set cells/!b; :Loop; N; /}/!b Loop; s/.*/set cells {$cell_def}/" -i file
```

- `/set cells/!b` : Look for set cells, if not found go to next line
- `:Loop` : label used to merge multiple lines
- `N` : append the next line
- `/}/!b Loop` : Look for an }, if not found go back to label Loop. In practice the loop reads a new line until the } is found
- `s/.*/set cells {$cell_def}/` : replace everything with my own set cells command. At this point the whole statement including the {.*} should be read.

Thank you for the help everybody

Answer (score 3):

If it must be `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak ':a;N;$!ba;s/set cells {.*}/set cells{\n'$cell_variable'\n}/g' file
```

- `-i.bak` creates a backup of the original file before editing inline.
- `:a` create label `a` to jump back.
- `N` append the next line of input into the pattern space.
- `$!` if it's not the last line...

  - `ba` jump back to label `a`
- `s///g` search and replace the patterns

---

A simpler solution with `perl`:

```
perl -0777 -i.bak -pe "s/set cells \{.*\}/set cells{\n$cell_variable\n}/igs" file
```

- `-0777` causes perl to slurp files whole.
- `-i.bak` creates a backup of the original file before editing inline.